# Nodemon start only webserver (not db server) in Node

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am using nodemon to restart my node application when ever changes were made. My problem is every time both web-server and DB server are restarting after code changes were made. I am using Oracle DB. below is my app.js code:

```
const webServer = require('./services/web-server.js');
const database = require('./services/database.js');
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.js');
const defaultThreadPoolSize = 4;

async function startup() {
  console.log('Starting application');

  //Initializing web server module
  try {
    console.log('Initializing web server module');

    await webServer.initialize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }

  //Initializing the Oracle DB
  try {
    console.log('Initializing database module');

    await database.initialize(); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);

    process.exit(1); // Non-zero failure code
  }

  //Stopping Oracle DB
   /*try {
    console.log('Closing database module');

    await database.close(); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Encountered error', e);

    err = err || e;
  }*/


}

startup();
```

services/web-server.js, I am creating a http server like below:

```
httpServer = http.createServer(app);
```

services/database.js, I am creating a pool for Oracle:

```
  const pool = await oracledb.createPool(dbConfig.hrPool);
```

Please suggest me how can I restart only web-server with nodemon? I don't want DB connection to restart always...

Comment: What is your database? How is it launched? What's in service/database.js and config/database.js ?

Comment: I am using Oracle DB, I have updated my question, please check @Veve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database server doesn't restart every time you restart your node application.

What's happening is your node is recreating the connection to the database every time it's restarted, which is normal and can't be avoided.

You can check this by connecting to your Oracle server and doing queries on it while your node application is stopped.

Comment: Is there a way that I don't want to recreate a connection everytime when ever node server restarts?

Comment: Yes: don't use a database. When your application restart, it's like it never ran before, like it started for the first time: you have to do a first connection to the database in order to access it.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample solution for this?

Comment: Not using database? Remove the line at the top `const database = require('./services/database.js');`, and remove the try catch code block below `//Initializing the Oracle DB`

Comment: @sony, as Veve has already stated, you cannot avoid recreating your connection pool when you restart the app. You could, however, lower the number of connections you're creating in the pool to say, 1. That would reduce the amount of time it takes to do the work.